# iterar en un objeto para encontrar una propiedad con valor true

Tags: typescript

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual requiero recorrer este array que muestro en la imagen, que busque siempre sobre la pripiedad "`is_deleted`" y encuentre el primero que está en false

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que tengo es el siguiente

```js
getItemCommentData(validateFields?: boolean) {
    let params = {
      evaluationId: this.dataFromItem.evaluation_id,
      metaId: this.dataFromItem.field_id,
    };
    this.commentService.getDataComment(params).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.hideSpinner(this.spinner_comment);
        console.log("COMMENT DATA", res.data);
        // const replies_count = res.data.filter(data => data.approved)[0]?  +res.data.filter(data => data.approved)[0].replies.replies_count : 0;
        let replies_count = 0;
        const answered_comments = res.data.filter((data) => data.approved);
        console.log({ answered_comments });

        if (answered_comments.length > 0) {
          answered_comments.map((ac) => {
            replies_count += +ac.replies.replies_count;
          });
        }
        console.log({ replies_count });

        this.updateNumCommnts.emit({
          length: res.data.filter((field) => field.is_deleted == false).length,
          replies_count: replies_count,
          validateFields,
        });
        //  console.log(this.currentUser.roles[0].description);

        switch (this.currentUser.roles[0].description) {
          case this.allRoles.crp:
            this.commentsByCol = res.data.filter((data) => data.approved);
            console.log(this.commentsByCol + "Commentsbycol");

            this.currentComment = this.commentsByCol.find(
              (comment) => comment.approved
            );
            this.crpComment = true;
            break;
          default:
            this.commentsByCol = res.data;
            break;
        }
        // console.log(this.commentsByCol);

        this.commentsByCol.forEach((comment) => {
          if (comment.replies.replies_count != "0") {
            comment.isCollapsed = true;
            this.getCommentReplies(comment);
          }
          
          //ACÁ ES DONDE ESTOY HACIENDO LA FUNCIÓN
          
          this.commentsByCol.forEach(element => {
            for (const notDeleted in element) {
              console.log(notDeleted + ':' + element[notDeleted])
              if(notDeleted){
                
              }
            }
          });
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("getItemCommentData", error);
        this.hideSpinner(this.spinner_comment);
        this.alertService.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Este codigo me retorna absolutamente todas las propiedades pero requiero que me itere sobre la cantidad de comentarios que hayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repliqué parte del código para el ejemplo:

```js
const testJson = {
    commentsByCol: [
        {
            approved: true,
            createdAt: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
            is_deleted: true,
        },
        {
            approved: true,
            createdAt: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
            is_deleted: true,
        },
        {
            approved: false,
            createdAt: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
            is_deleted: false,
        },
        {
            approved: false,
            createdAt: '2019-33-01T00:00:00.000Z',
            is_deleted: false,
        },
    ]
};

const firstDeleted = testJson.commentsByCol
    .filter((comment) => !comment.is_deleted)[0];

// o bien con

const firstDeleted2 = testJson.commentsByCol
.find((comment) => !comment.is_deleted);


console.log(firstDeleted);
console.log(firstDeleted2);
```

Lo adaptas al código y listo.

Saludos;